# WebDev.WebServer40.exe has stopped working - File not found

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

If I try to run my asp.net mvc web app in Visual Studio Debugger (by pressing F5) I now get this error:

> WebDev.WebServer40.exe has stopped working
>
> Additional details:
>
> Problem signature:
> Problem Event Name:CLR20r3
> Problem Signature 01:webdev.webserver40.exe
> Problem Signature 02:11.0.50727.1
> Problem Signature 03:5011ca7e
> Problem Signature 04:WebDev.WebServer40
> Problem Signature 05:11.0.50727.1
> Problem Signature 06:5011ca7e
> Problem Signature 07:88
> Problem Signature 08:19e
> Problem Signature 09:System.IO.FileNotFoundException
> OS Version:6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
> Locale ID:2057
> Additional Information 1:0a9e
> Additional Information 2:0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
> Additional Information 3:0a9e
> Additional Information 4:0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

If I choose the option to "Debug the program", it opens up in VS with the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

It was working / deugging fine! I haven't changed anything that I know about

I've cleared out the asp.net temp files etc... and even installed the VS 2012 update, but nothing seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problems was deleting all cookies.